# Create Azure Boards work item for each test case failure data collected from JSON file from Allure-results folder

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml, workitem, azure-boards

Could you please help with some idea on how to create work-item on azure-boards during the execution of devops build pipeline YAML (it does allure report generation)

I have the following python script to catch the failed test case details from json files generated from Allure-results. After that, I am not able to proceed with any further logic.

Could you help with any REST API or standalone method which I can use in the YAML pipeline itself as the subsequent step/task followed by the python script.

```
        - task: PythonScript@0
          inputs:
            scriptSource: 'inline'
            script: |
              import json
              import glob
              src = "allure-results/"
              files = glob.glob('allure-results/*.json', recursive=True)
              
              for single_file in files:
                with open(single_file,'r') as f:
                  print(single_file)
                  # Use 'try-except' to skip files that may be missing data
                  try:
                    json_file = json.load(f)
                    if json_file['status'] != 'passed':
                      tsName = json_file['name']
                      tsStatus = json_file['status']
                      tsErrMsg = json_file['statusDetails']['message']
                      tsTrace = json_file['statusDetails']['trace']
                      tsSeverity = json_file['labels'][0]['name']
                      tsSevType = json_file['labels'][0]['value']
                      # print(tsName,"\n",tsStatus,"\n",tsErrMsg,"\n",tsTrace,"\n",tsSeverity,"\n",tsSevType,"\n")
                      data = [tsName, tsStatus, tsErrMsg, tsTrace, tsSeverity, tsSevType]
                      print(*data, sep = "\n")
                  except KeyError:
                    pass
                    # print(f'Skipping {single_file}')
            workingDirectory: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)'
```

I have an idea on how to create the work-item on pipeline failure but want to know how I can create work-item on each testcase failed data stored in python list from the above script.

Just FYI.. I use the below code is for creating work-item on pipeline failure.

```
    - bash: |
        az boards work-item create \
          --title "Build $(build.buildNumber) failed" \
          --type issue \
          --org $(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri) \
          --project $(System.TeamProject)
      env: 
        AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
      displayName: 'Create work item on failure'
```